# How to generate combinations with repetition of only one element using python

Tags: python

I am a Python newbie and just come across the "itertools" module. I want to create this specific type of combinations with multiple lists that:

1) repeat the first element of the latter list
2) the latter value is in ascending order within a combination

e.g. for these two lists

```py
    a=[1,2,3]
    b=[None,4,5,6]
```

The desired outcome is

```
    [(1, None), (2, None), (3, None)]
    [(1, None), (2, None), (3, 4)]
    [(1, None), (2, None), (3, 5)]
    [(1, None), (2, None), (3, 6)]
    [(1, None), (2, 4), (3, None)]
    [(1, None), (2, 4), (3, 5)]
    [(1, None), (2, 4), (3, 6)]
    [(1, None), (2, 5), (3, None)]
    [(1, None), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
    [(1, None), (2, 6), (3, None)]
    [(1, 4), (2, None), (3, None)]
    [(1, 4), (2, None), (3, 5)]
    [(1, 4), (2, None), (3, 6)]
    [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, None)]
    [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
    [(1, 4), (2, 6), (3, None)]
    [(1, 5), (2, None), (3, None)]
    [(1, 5), (2, None), (3, 6)]
    [(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, None)]
    [(1, 6), (2, None), (3, None)]
```

That is C(n+2,m) combinations in total, where n=len(b) and m=len(a). In this case, there are C(4+2,3)=20 combinations.

I wonder if there is an efficient way of using "itertools" to get the results. Also, please note that there may be more than 2 lists, e.g. there could be a c=[None,7,8,9,10], resulting in 3 elements within each tuple.

EDIT:
I have managed to get what I want using the code below, which works although inefficient. Please let me know if you have a better way of solving this issue. Thank you:)

```py
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
def create_none(lst):
    none_list=[]
    for Index in range(len(lst)):
        none_list.append(None)
    return none_list
extended_list=create_none(a)[:]
extended_list.extend(b)  

for i in itertools.combinations(extended_list,len(a)):
    sublist=list(zip(a,i))
    print(sublist)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in itertools module: [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.product). It does exactly what you need.

Example:

```
a = [None,1,2]
list(itertools.product(a, repeat=3))

[(None, None, None),
 (None, None, 1),
 (None, None, 2),
 (None, 1, None),
 (None, 1, 1),
 (None, 1, 2),
 (None, 2, None),
 (None, 2, 1),
 (None, 2, 2),
 (1, None, None),
 (1, None, 1),
 (1, None, 2),
 (1, 1, None),
 (1, 1, 1),
...
```

Your problem can be solved by this code:

`[list(zip(a, elem))for elem in itertools.product(b, repeat=3)]`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. However, according to the output, the latter value in the tuples within each combination did not seem to be in ascending order. Also, every element in list b seemed to be repeated whereas I only want the first element, which is 'None', to be repeated.